# How to get alternating height in css grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I mean first item has x height, then second has y height and then third has x and so on..

I tried repeat but can't understand the syntax.

```
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    grid-template-rows: repeat();
    gap:2px;
```

Edit : Forgot to add this (noob here , i apologise!)

If first row is : x y x y
second row should be : y x y x
third should be : x y x y
fourth so on

[image: Like this]

Comment: All cells in a row have equal height. There is nothing you can do about it within your `grid-template-rows` definition, but you can work with `max-height` on the items **in** the cells.

Comment: if elements in first row have height x y x y then elements in below row should cover that by being y x y x

Comment: You should have said that in the question! I edited my answer to provide a solution for that.

Comment: @MaazAhmadKhan If any of these answers solves your problem (and I think mine does), and you do not need any additional help, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: @JannesCarpentier Thanks bro!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**edit** Apparantly you are looking for this: 
**edit 2** I figured out how to do it with some `:nth-child()` rules

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-gap: 8px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: red;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(8n+1),
.grid-item:nth-child(8n+3),
.grid-item:nth-child(8n+5),
.grid-item:nth-child(8n+6) {
  grid-row: span 2;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All cells in a row have equal height. There is nothing you can do about it within your `grid-template-rows` definition, but you can work with `max-height` on the cells.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  gap: 5px;
}

.grid > div {
  background-color: #f00;
}

.grid > div:nth-child(even) {
  max-height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div class="half-height"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="half-height"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="half-height"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="half-height"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the grid cells (individual items) you have to target them directly instead of from the parent. Here's a simple example using `nth-child` selectors. Here's a bunch of different ones you could use to make a pattern of your choosing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#Examples

Also, you don't have to use explicit heights like I did, that was just a quick way of showing what I mean. They could be `max-height` or limited some other way.

Image:

[image]